# Elastic Search - sort on should and must

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this problem, i want to sort on 2 match, and my code look like this right now (its in php array)

```
$data = [
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
            'must' => [
                'multi_match' => [
                    'query' => $q,
                    'fields' => ['Fulltext'],
                    'type' => 'cross_fields',
                    'operator' => 'and'
                ]
            ],
            'should' => [
                'match' => [
                    'Title' => $q,
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'aggregations' => [
        'categorys' => [
            'terms' => [
                'field' => 'Categorys.value',
                'size' => $category_size
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'size' => $product_size,
    'sort' => [
        'Popular' => [
            'order' => 'desc'
        ]
    ]
];
```

The problem in this sort i want to sort it by "Popular" but, its not first sort on match in "should" and then after in "must" so my question is.

How can i start sorting in the first match points, and then sort in the secound match points based on Popular field?

The problem is i want to search in prouct where the query match in Title is higher importen then in Fulltext field.

so if i get 10 resualt based on Title and the score are highter then the next 10 resualt based on Fulltext, but we have 3 reusalt from Title and 2 from Fulltext where Probular is gretnder then 0 then this match shut be view'en and sorted by (_score, Popular) if Popular is greather then zero else sort just based on (_score)

Can eny body help me with this question?

Comment: ES should reject this query actually since your `should` clause is not properly located, it should be inside your `bool` clause.

Comment: sorry, the copy/past make me to mistake, its edit now thanks :)

Comment: You should first try adding a higher `boost` to your title match in `should`. Add `'boost' => 3` inside your `match` clause, does it work?

Comment: "minimum_should_match" => 1 and  "boost" => 1 look like its working, i will test more, :) but yes look like this working, can you explain what is doing becures i can se its working but not relly understand how its giving sens :)

Comment: By using a `boost` factor, you're giving more importance to the `match` query over the other. Beware though, if you add `minimum_should_match: 1`, you're basically saying that your `should` clause is in fact a `must`

Comment: Orh, now its not finding match whith Popular 0 if the orther stuff not matching, :) i use it on a search pages to, and here its shut found all resualt ofc, but sorting after popular where its sorting by "should" and then "must" if you understand?